# How to merge two queried results in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a single form which I am using to create and edit information.
I am using Form::model to show all the data in the edit form which are queried from the database. Now I had to add another form part whose data is being stored in a different table. But I need to show those data during edit in the same form. I have tried to put two parameter in the form:model which did not work or I am doing it wrong.

```
{!! Form::model([$employee_data,$edu_info],['route'=>['employee.update',$employee_data->id],'method'=>'put','files'=> true]) !!}
```

Then I tried to merge the queried data in my controller like this:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $edit_info['title'] = 'Edit User';
    $edit_info['country'] = Country::all();
    $employee_basic = Employee::withTrashed()->where('id',$id)->first();
    $employee_edu = EmployeeEdu::withTrashed()->where('employee_id',$id)->first();
    $employee_all_data = $employee_basic->merge($employee_edu);
    $employee_all_data->all();
    $edit_info['employee_data'] = $employee_all_data;
    return view('admin.employee.edit',$edit_info);
}
```

This did not work either. I get the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::merge()
```

How can I achieve my intended result?

EDIT: I tried to use `->get()` instead of `->first()`, In this case I do not get the error but my merge does not work as when I `dd($employee_all_data)` it gives me only the value of `$employee_edu`.

Comment: What's your desired result?

Comment: To merge those two objects in one object. Those data are in different tables.

Comment: How should they get merged? They both have an `id`, what `id` should `$employee_all_data` have?

Comment: What `$employee_edu` data should `$employee_all_data` contain?

Comment: `$employee_all_data` should have the `id (primary key)` from employees table only. I don't need the `id` of `employee_edus` table.
I have tried:
`EmployeeEdu::withTrashed()->where('employee_id',$id)->except('id')->first()`
This is also giving me an error.
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::except()`

Comment: You want to add the attributes of `$employee_edu` (except `id`) to the attributes of `$employee_basic`?

Comment: Well yes as I don't need that id. Now When I am merging both of the Objects I only get the data of the object that I merged. Like `$employee_all_data = $employee_basic->merge($employee_edu);` I only get the values of `$employee_edu` . So basically it's not merging but replacing the values of `$employee_basic`.

Comment: Please add some sample attributes to your question. Do `Employee` and `EmployeeEdu` have any other attributes in common (besides `id`)?

Comment: None. They have completely different attributes. Tho `employee_edu` table has `employee_id` attribute which contains the primary key (id) of `employee` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$employee_all_data = $employee_basic->toArray() + $employee_edu->toArray();
```